# how to hide column chart gridlines xlsxwriter

Tags: python, charts, hide, xlsxwriter, gridlines

How do I hide the column grid lines on a chart in xlsxwriter.
I looked at the [documentation page](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_charts.html) in the chart formatting section and wasn't able to find any example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for the [chart class](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/chart.html#chart-class), there are the methods `set_x_axis` and `set_y_axis`. It takes a dictionary of formatting options. One of the options you can pass is `{'visible': False}`.

You can also configure just the major or minor gridlines with `{'major_gridlines' :{'visible': False}}`

Comment: Thanks Morgan for replying, You right! I used this `chart.set_x_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': True},})` and it WORKS!